# Handlebars template not rendering info on iOS7 Safari

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

I am currently in charge of an Backbone/Handlebars/Coffeescript site; m.bachcare.co.nz

The site seems to be going well except for a bug on iOS7 not showing some property rates in the availability tab on a certain month. The data is not corrupt, and logs seem to show it being parsed from JSON correctly. No other errors.

That is on Bachwood in September:

http://m.bachcare.co.nz/property/2988

The code for the Calendar in Handlebars is:

```
<div class="avail-calendar-section">
    <div class="avail-calendar">
    {{log month}}
    {{#calendarDays month currentAvailability currentRates specials selectedDates.start selectedDates.end calendarEnd minDate type}}

        {{#if isStartOfWeek}}
        <div class="avail-calendar-week">
        {{/if}}

            {{log rate}}

            <div class="
                avail-calendar-date
                {{#if currentRates.length}}
                    {{#if_eq rate compare=0}}{{#if isInMonth}}avail-calendar-date-no-rate {{/if}}{{/if_eq}}
                    {{#if isSpecial}}avail-calendar-date-special {{/if}}
                {{/if}}
                {{#if currentAvailability.length}}
                    {{#unless isInPast}}{{#if isInMonth}}{{#if isAvailable}}avail-calendar-date-available {{else}}avail-calendar-date-unavailable {{/if}}{{/if}}{{/unless}}
                {{/if}}
                {{#if isDisabled}}avail-calendar-date-disabled {{/if}}
                {{#if isSelected}}avail-calendar-date-selected {{/if}}
                {{#if isToday}}avail-calendar-date-today {{/if}}
                {{#if isInPast}}avail-calendar-date-past {{/if}}
                {{#if isInFuture}}avail-calendar-date-future {{/if}}
                {{#unless isInMonth}}avail-calendar-date-skirt {{/unless}}"

                data-date="{{formatDate date 'YYYY-MM-DD'}}">
                <div class="avail-calendar-date-value">
                    {{#if isInMonth}}
                        {{#if isToday}}
                            Today
                        {{else}}
                            {{formatDate date 'D'}}
                        {{/if}}
                    {{/if}}
                </div>

                {{#if isInMonth}}
                <div class="avail-calendar-date-rate">
                    {{#if rate}}{{#unless_eq rate compare=0}}
                        $<span class="avail-calendar-date-rate-value">{{rate}}</span>
                    {{/unless_eq}}
                    {{else}}
                        {{#if_eq type compare="checkout"}}
                            {{#if isCheckIn}}
                            <span class="check-in-label">checkin</span>
                            {{/if}}
                        {{/if_eq}}
                        {{#if_eq type compare="checkout"}}
                            {{#if isCheckOut}}
                            <span class="check-out-label">checkout</span>
                            {{/if}}
                        {{/if_eq}}
                    {{/if}}
                </div>
                {{/if}}

            </div>

        {{#if isEndOfWeek}}
        </div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/calendarDays}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I will post any other code requested.

Comment: Why are you using Handlebars with Angular? I don't think you should do that.

Comment: is this now fixed? tried looking at it using IOS 7.0.4 and safari but September 2014 looks the same as when i view in chrome on my desktop.

Comment: @AndyGaskell it might be Backbone, then. I didn't build the site.

Comment: @Quince are you looking at that specific property?

Comment: wait js property or house property? house property i followed the link you gave click availability then changed the date to September. js property i assumed it was the price appearing in the calendar under the day.

Comment: here is what i see on the ipad http://imgur.com/hPelxEM

Comment: Yes, house property. Okay, so that makes it more annoying if it only breaks for some...

Comment: @AndyGaskell had a quick search in the source and found backbone referenced so I'll change the question

Comment: is it definitely not making it's way to the html, if you inspect where it should be it's not just hidden due to styling issues?

Comment: @Quince is that the latest version? I think this bug has only recently come into being

Comment: @Quince no, the values are not being put into the HTML.

Comment: @BeaverusIV no it's not the latest in fact I think they are on 7.1 something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57560/discussion-between-beaverusiv-and-quince). Ok, chat isn't working for me.

Comment: Could it be a JS issue with Safari? afaict all the JSON gets there fine from the log output. It's weird how it is just that one month. the data is nothing complicated (array of dates with corresponding booleans).

Comment: HI tired using the chat but never used it before so not sure if you have to be in the room to see the messages, if you have already seen this let me know and i'll delete this comment.

Comment: Going through the debugger in chrome so not sure if the code layout is the same but i see there is an App.Collection.Rates.js in here their is a getByDateRange function. when this returns it's success it goes to completeDateRange, now normally this returns an array of the data range but in the case of june 2015 (and i suspect the others as well) it is returning false. You can see this as when the Handlebars helper function runs currentRates is false so nothing displays.

Comment: Oh also to let you know this project also uses Marionette

Comment: @Quince so that could cause browser specific issues? fyi there are no dates after June 2015 for any property.

Comment: Not sure but it's at that point the currentRates is set to false and so there fore does not display, it could be the way dates are handled on the different browsers or something else but finding out why it return false there will be the key to fixing this. June is a good example to use as it always doesn't display the rates for the days that are available in june no matter what browser you are using.

Comment: @Quince as I said they don't display on purpose. The calendar only goes to May 31 2015.

Comment: Thanks anyway you guys for helping me look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding an hour to the date. The problem is iOS and its non-handling of daylight savings. This is a temporary fix which needs to be applied and removed during the year as DST changes.

From:

```
parse: (resp) ->
    rate : parseFloat(resp.rate)
    date : moment(resp.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate()
```

To:

```
   parse: (resp) ->
        rate : parseFloat(resp.rate)
        date : moment(resp.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').add(1, 'hours').toDate()
```